# How to open a file using Visual Studio Code in Hyper?

Tags: command-line-interface, git-bash, hyper

I am new to CLI and was trying to open a text file using Visual Studio Code

**$ start Visual Studio Code Text2.txt**

The result was

**The system cannot find the file Visual**

Answer (score 0):

You can use "code" instead of "Visual Studio Code".

For example: If there is a file demo.txt, typing below command works.

```
start code demo.txt
```